# Disable wordpress gif compression?

Tags: media

Is it possible to disable the default gif compression in Wordpress.
I'm uploading animated gifs and they are turning soft.

Any advice much appreciated.

Attached is a screen grab illustrating the issue. lhs is the gif dragged into browser from the desktop, rhs is the gif as it appears on my website.

[image]

thanks
Nigel

Comment: WP doesn't compress GIF's, it recompresses JPEG's, are you sure you're not referring to resizing?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main concerns with using animated gifs in WordPress: dimensions and file size.

When you upload a gif file to the media library, WordPress stores the original file and additional files for different sizes ( medium, thumbnail ). Gifs of other sizes will be stored with one frame of animation only, so they will lose their animation capability. While adding an animated gif into a post/page, always select the `full size` ( this is the only one which preserves animation ).

Animated gifs could be very large. It is important to compress them before uploading to the media library. To compress them without losing quality, you should use a program employing lossless compression algorithm. You can find a good one, called [Gifsicle on GitHub](https://github.com/kohler/gifsicle). This is a command line tool, so if you are not comfortable with command line, you can find other programs offering GUI. For Mac - [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac), for Windows - [FileOptimizer](http://nikkhokkho.sourceforge.net/static.php?page=FileOptimizer). There is also a web application [Compressor.io](https://compressor.io/) available.

Comment: Hi Frank Yep I've disabled the additional file size generation, I only have the original Gif I loaded. I don't want this compressed or resized as I've already set it up using Gifsicle and Imagemagick.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is Wordpress is applying compression to it somewhere as it is noticeably softer once displayed in post.

Comment: Any idea how to disable this compression?

Comment: As @TomJNowell said, WordPress does not compress GIFs. You can test it. Upload your GIF using Media Library. Add it to your post/page. Now use FTP and upload your source GIF overwriting it in uploads folder. Rename your source GIF and upload it with Media Library. Add it to your post next to your first image. You can compare them. They are identical.

Comment: Is this test valid?  I drag my gif from my desktop to a browser window, it looks fine. I upload the same gif to Wordpress, it looks fine if I view it in the media library - the same as the gif in the browser window. When I post it however it becomes soft. Could it be something to do with the way the theme handles images?  thanks..

Comment: You could check in browser console if the gif is scaled. In chrome browser you can check the image - you get the original size and the size rendered.